# Is it legal to initialize a POD member of a base class before its constructor is called when it's not going to be initialized by it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

In the following code:

```
class Base
{
protected:
  int v;

  Base( void * ) { /* doesn't touch v at any point */ }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  // Changes Base::v before calling Base::Base
  Derived(): Base( ( (void )( v = 42 ), nullptr ) ) {}
};
```

`Derived::Derived` changes a POD member variable `Base::v` before calling `Base::Base`. It's known that `Base::Base` isn't touching `v` at all. The goal is to have `Base::v` initialized to `42` after leaving `Derived::Derived`.

While this should technically work (`Base::v` already has space allocated for it in memory when `Derived::Derived` is called, and no code in `Base::Base` is ever touching it), the question is, is this legal? More specifically, does this at any point imply any undefined behavior, which compilers famously like to optimize-out?

Note that this question is purely for language lawyers. I'm not asking whether there are better ways of doing this (in most cases there obviously are), and I'm not trying to solve any specific problem other than trying to learn more about C++ from the point of view of the C++ standard.

Comment: Fwiw, I'm seeing a warning:  `Dragonroot.cpp:13:31: warning: base class 'Base' is uninitialized when used here to access 'Base::v' [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: I can't see that this as legal. The life of `Base` hasn't started yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not valid:

[class.cdtor/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/class.cdtor#1)

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior.

Also see the [example](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/class.cdtor#2) below the above paragraph:

```cpp
struct W { int j; };
struct X : public virtual W { };
struct Y {
  int* p;
  X x;
  Y() : p(&x.j) {   // undefined, x is not yet constructed
  }
};
```